# Can't add new source file in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I installed VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop on Windows 8. But I can't add source file to the project: there are no elements to choose.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8wCV.jpg

Comment: Do you see a Project tab?

Comment: That has got to be the smallest screenshot I have ever seen

Comment: +1, @AngeloGeels. Exactly what I was going to say.

Comment: I have Win8 Pro. But I can't even install VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. This is not what the "supported operating system" says. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-ultimate-2012#product-edition-ultimate-requirements

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. Started today just out of no where. The only thing I could find about it was this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/802161/visual-studio-2013-express-rc-cant-add-new-file-for-c-project

No solution though, unfortunately